# How do I bring the correct image to my pushed page?

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin

I have 2 different images and the idea is that when you click either of them you should get to a new page and the new page should show the image that you picked, I am not getting it to work. I know I can make 2 different pages but I want to refine my code as much as possible.

this is the code:

```
public PicturePage ()
    {
        image1.Clicked += OnButtonClicked; //x:name of my image in xaml.

        image2.Clicked += OnButtonClicked; //x:name of my second image in xaml.

    }


async void OnButtonClicked(Object sender, EventArgs args)
    {

        Navigation.PushAsync (new PictureDetailPage ()); //how will the code know what the user clicked?

    }
```

Comment: Use the debugger to inspect the values of the `sender` object. That should lead you to the object which was clicked; from that, you can derive which image to show.

Comment: yeah I know it has something to do with sender, when I sent the info from a pin to a new page i used Pin pin = (Pin)sender; but i am not sure how to do it with images x:name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Xamarin.Forms element has a StyleId property, which you can use to assign a user defined value for identifying the element.

In your XAML:

```
<Image x:Name="Image1" StyleId="Image1" ... />
```

and in the code behind:

```
async void OnButtonClicked(Object sender, EventArgs args)
{

    Image image = (Image) sender;

    // pass the value of the StyleId string to the detail page
    Navigation.PushAsync (new PictureDetailPage (image.StyleId));

}
```

Comment: Error: Cannot cast source type to destination type.

Comment: I use this code on the "recieving-page" : public PictureDetailPage (string thePic)
  {
   InitializeComponent ();

   thePicture.Source = thePic;
  }  

//thePicture is an image from my xaml.

Comment: you have to create a FileImageSource using the path/name of the image, and then assign that to the Image's Source property

Comment: on the PictureDetailPage or PicturePage?

Comment: Try it on the page that is causing you problems.

Comment: yeah the picturepage. this code:  Image image = (Image) sender;
not sure how i can create a fileimagesource, i have not done it before

Comment: I'm not going to spoon feed answers to you.  Look at the docs and samples; do some research; use Google, etc.  SO should not be the first thing you try every time you run into a problem

Comment: Ah ok, just thought it sorta was connected to the question. Well I will start a new thread with that then. Thanks alot jason. Upvoting your answer.